# Action for image on hover by css

Tags: image, css, responsive

I have one question about css. Here is example.
html:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

css:

```
.image {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.image:hover {
    background-size: 120% 120%;
}
```

So In this example everything working fine. When I hover on image, image is zoomed. However I have a lot of images like this and it's not good for SEO to use for every image div, and I want to use < img > tag but there isn't such thing like "background-size". Is there any way to do so with img?

Comment: Yes there is also another way. You can use img tag give `scale property to zoom effect.

Comment: I have tried it, but the result isn't as I want. When I use background-size property, the dimensions of div didn't change, only the size, but when I use transform scale, the dimensions also increased.

Comment: Please see my answer. I think this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it didn't because I want to do something else. I want this image have the same 250x250px when it hovered, but the zoom of this should be changed when it hovered.

Comment: What you want to do..? Can you explain me..?

Comment: I have image with width=250px and height=250px. When I use scale the width and height also increased as size, but I want the width and height be the same 250px and the size increased. Is this explanation good?

Comment: sorry but that is not possible. and one thing when you used `background-size:120% 120%` that time also img dimension is increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```css
.image {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 100px;

}

.image:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA">
```

Comment: The problem in your suggestion is that when I use scale for image, it will increase the special dimension of image, in my case width: 250px and height: 250px;  But I want to be the same dimension, and zoomed when it hovered.

Comment: Do you want a magnifier?

Comment: No not exactly. Please look at comments below the question. I have explained what I want better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have done by scale property.

```css
.image{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.image img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.image:hover img {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet helps you.

```css
.image{
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.image:hover img {
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to achieve but in your code

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

is equivalent in display to

```
<div><img class="image" /></div>
```